# How to add a link to images based on some condition using typescript and react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to add a link to the image based on some condition using javascript and react.

what i am trying to do?

i have mobile and desktop images.

under mobile image i have text saying switch to mobile and
is clickable if the users current url is not matching mobile_url.
if the users current url matches the mobile_url then the text would be "current version" and is not clickable.

under desktop image i have text saying switch to desktop and
is clickable if the users current url is not matching desktop_url
if the users current url matches the desktop_url then the text would be "current version" and is not clickable.

below is my code that works,

```
function Parent () {
    const currentUrl = window.location.origin + '/';
    return (
        <div className="Wrapper">
            <Dialog>
                <span>Select Version</span>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="block">
                        <span>Mobile</span>
                        <div className="image_wrapper"> // want to add a link here too
                            <img src={mobile} width={50} />
                        </div>
                        <span>
                            {current_url === mobile_url ? (
                                'Current version'
                            ) : (
                                <a href={mobile_url}>Switch to mobile</a>
                            )}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="block">
                        <span>Desktop</span>
                        <div className="image_wrapper"> //want to add a link here too
                            <img src={desktop} width={50} />
                        </div>
                        <span>
                            {current_url === desktop_url ? (
                                'Current version'
                            ) : (
                                <a href={desktop_url}>Switch to desktop</a>
                            )}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
       );
   }
```

Now what i want to do is as the texts switch to mobile and switch to desktops are clickable and have a link to an url. similarly i want to have links to the images mobile and desktop and should be clickable based on same conditions like texts have.

so for mobile image if current url is same as mobile_url then image is not clickable. if current url doesnt match with mobile_url then image is clickable and redirects to mobile_url

and for desktop image if current_url is same as desktop_url then image is not clickable. if current url doesnt match with desktop_url then image is clickable and redirects to desktop_url

how can i do it. could someone help me with this. thanks.

**EDIT:**

i have tried like below and the images are not seen.

```
import desktop from '../image/desktop.svg';
import mobile from '../image/mobile.svg';

interface Props {
    src: any; //what should be the type here
    width: any; //what should be the type here
}
function RenderImage({src, width}: Props) {
    return (
        <div className="image_wrapper">
            <img src={src} width={width}/>
        </div>
    );
}

function Parent () {
    const currentUrl = window.location.origin + '/';
    return (
        <div className="Wrapper">
            <Dialog>
                <span>Select Version</span>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="block">
                        <span>Mobile</span>
                        {current_url === mobile_url ? (
                            <a href={mobile_url}>
                                <Image src={mobile} width={50}/>
                            </a> ): (
                                <Image src={mobile} width={50} />
                            )
                        }
                        <span>
                            {current_url === mobile_url ? (
                                'Current version'
                            ) : (
                                <a href={mobile_url}>Switch to mobile</a>
                            )}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="block">
                        <span>Desktop</span>
                        {current_url === desktop_url ? (
                            <a href={desktop_url}>
                                <Image src={desktop} width={width}/>
                            </a> ) : (
                                <Image src={desktop} width={width} />
                        }
                        <span>
                            {current_url === desktop_url ? (
                                'Current version'
                            ) : (
                                <a href={desktop_url}>Switch to desktop</a>
                            )}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
       );
   }
```

this works fine but what should be the types for src and width in this case thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would decide what component renders before your return.

```
export default function Parent() {
    const pathname = window.location.pathname;
    const customElement = pathname === 'your mobile url'? // Check if matches
        <a href={mobile_url}>Switch to mobile</a> :  // if so return this one
        <a href={desktop_url}>Switch to desktop</a> //else this

    return (
        <div className="Wrapper">
            <Dialog>
                <span>Select Version</span>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="block">
                        <span>Mobile</span>
                        <div className="image_wrapper"> 
                            <img src={mobile} width={50} />
                        </div>
                  <span>{customElement}</span>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
               </Dialog>
              </div>
       );
   }
```

You can do the same with the images if you want a different one to display based upon current path.

Comment: thanks i have added to my question what i have tried. do you know what type to be used for src in my tried answer?